# how to use string variable call the same name Function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use string parameter to call the same name function

At one time i try call this method ,but also need function argument

```
Function().apply
```

so, I want know how to implementation this idea? thx

Comment: Dart does not support runtime reflection, so there is no built-in way to do this.  You will need to manually create your own mapping of `String`s to functions.

Comment: this example function can do in flutter https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/function-arguments-default-optional-named